# Is there any way to pass PHP object as JavaScript parameter in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I do project using Laravel 5. I show table from view and I want to when click this link pass it is data value all data to JavaScript function. I am try to several way but cannot do it.

```
  @foreach ($basl_officers as $basl_officer)
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="#"   onClick="functionOne($basl_officer)"  >{{ $basl_officer->officerName }} </a></td>        
                            <td align='center'>
                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['basl_officers_page.destroy',$basl_officer->id]]) !!}
                                <a href="{{route('basl_officers_page.edit',$basl_officer->id)}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </a> &nbsp &nbsp
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> 
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
 @endforeach
```

JavaScript Code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function functionOne(x) {
    alert('You clicked the top text' + x);
}
function functionTwo() {
    alert('You clicked the bottom text');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
onClick="functionOne({{ json_encode($basl_officer) }})"
```

Comment: Thank you @James Flight  ok i think now ,data is pass . plz. can you tell me any way to de code this object data within JavaScript function  .plz.

Comment: I think the object should already be decoded. Try console.log(x) and see if what is being passed to the function is an object.

Comment: I suppose that you should also `escape` the result of `json_encode($basl_officer)` since it will be in double quotes.

Comment: It shouldn't need escaping, as in Laravel 5 all `{{}}` statements are passed through `htmlentites()` by default. Docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data).

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work using this code inside my .blade file.

```
<script>
    var object = <?php echo json_encode($object) ?>;
    console.log(object);
</script>
```

This is assuming object is provided through your controller.